# Adding value to property if condition true

Tags: reactjs

I want to add
`last_organized_event_date_at: moment(event.endDate).unix()`

...if the following condition is true: `event.isLive || moment(event.endDate).isSame(moment(), "day")`

Otherwise, the value should not be passed. My version doesn't work right now.

```
if (user.id === event.organizer.ownerId) {
  organizer = {
    ...organizer,
    (event.isLive || moment(event.endDate).isSame(moment(), "day")) && last_organized_event_date_at: moment(event.endDate).unix(),
    company: {
      id: event.id,
      name: event.slug,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
organizer = {
  ...organizer,
  ...((event.isLive || moment(event.endDate).isSame(moment(), "day")) &&  {last_organized_event_date_at: moment(event.endDate).unix()} ),
  company: {
    id: event.id,
    name: event.slug,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to achieve this,

organizer = {
...organizer,
...((isLive || moment('2021-07-03').isSame(moment(), 'day')) && {
last_organized_event_date_at: moment('2021-07-04').unix()
}),
company: {
id: event.id,
name: event.slug
}
};

Checkout the working version - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xmg8dy?file=index.js